# How to do different anchor points for translation and rotation on a text element in an SVG

Tags: python, text, svg, rotation, transform

I want to build an SVG where I set text using one anchor point for the x,y translation and then a different anchor point for the rotation. Specifically, I want to translate the text to point (x,y) where (x,y) is the upper left corner of the text. Then I want to rotate the text about the its center point. I can't just translate the text using the center point as an anchor because it is impossible to get the width and height of the text in advance. (I am using Python)

Here's an image depicting the two anchor points I'd like to use.

[image: showing the two different anchor points on my svg]

Also I should note that I want to be able to view this file in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: If you don't know the width and height of the text, there is really no way to determine the centre of the text element.  I'm not sure I see a way around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a way for SVG with embedded Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/bLuc315m/3/

```
<svg width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 320 320" onload="init(this, 100, 100, 30)">
<script>
    function init(doc, x, y, ang) {
        var e = doc.querySelector("#txt");
        var b = e.getBoundingClientRect();
        var w = b.width;
        var h = b.height;
        e.setAttribute(
            "transform", 
            "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")"
            + "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) +")"        
            + "rotate(" + ang + ")"
            + "translate(" + (-w/2) + "," + (h/2) +")"        
        );
    }
</script>
<g stroke="#999" stroke-width="0.5">
    <path d="M100,0V320"/>
    <path d="M0,100H320"/>
</g>
<text id="txt" x="0" y="0" font-size="20" 
    fill="black" stroke="none">TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

But I don't know if Adobe Illustrator can manage this.